# When is CAMLparamX required?

Tags: c, garbage-collection, ocaml

I am writing an interface to a C-library using external declarations in OCaml. I used ctypes for testing but it involved a 100% overhead for fast calls (measured by a core_bench micro benchmark).

The functions look like this:

```
/* external _create_var : float -> int -> int -> int -> _npnum = "ocaml_tnp_number_create_var" ;; */
value ocaml_tnp_number_create_var(value v, value nr, value p, value o) {
  //CAMLparam4(v, nr, p, o);
  const int params = Int_val(p);
  const int order = Int_val(o);
  const int number = Int_val(nr);
  const double value = Double_val(v);
  return CTYPES_FROM_PTR(tnp_number_create_variable(value, number, params, order));
}
/* external _delete : _npnum -> unit = "ocaml_tnp_number_delete" ;; */
value ocaml_tnp_number_delete(value num) {
  //CAMLparam1(num);
  struct tnp_number* n = CTYPES_TO_PTR(num);
  tnp_number_delete(n);
  return Val_unit;
}
```

I borrowed the CTYPES_* macros, so I am basically moving pointers around as Int64 values.

```
#define CTYPES_FROM_PTR(P) caml_copy_int64((intptr_t)P)
#define CTYPES_TO_PTR(I64) ((void *)Int64_val(I64))
#define CTYPES_PTR_PLUS(I64, I) caml_copy_int64(Int64_val(I64) + I)
```

AFAIK, those values are represented as boxes which are tagged as "custom", which should be left untouched by the GC.

Do I need to uncomment the `CAMLparamX` macros to notify the GC about my usage or is it legal to omit them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comment in [`byterun/memory.h`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/byterun/memory.h#L139) your function **must** start with a `CAMLparamN` macro with all `value` parameters.

Comment: Unboxed value args such as integers need not be in CAMLparamN. See byterun/ints.c of OCaml compiler source code for such examples.

Comment: @camlspotter There is a gap between what is actually safe and what is specified as safe. The shortcut you mention and many others are undocumented. The documentation is as cited in this answer. The question is concerned with what is *legal*, not with what happens to work.